# KotlinTestEngine.discover() doesn't return any tests

Tags: junit, kotlin, junit5, kotlintest

My goal is to have a class which can find any tests written in kotlintest. I already have working code for Java/Scala/Groovy unit tests but can't get it to work for Kotlintest.

My discover code:

```
LauncherDiscoveryRequest request = LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.request().selectors(selectPackage("com.example")).build();
descriptor = new KotlinTestEngine().discover(request, uniqueId);
```

UniqueId has value of "engine:junit-example". I tried adding the following code but it doesn't work either.

```
new DiscoverySelectorResolver().resolveSelectors(discoveryRequest, descriptor);
```

The descriptor contains all the classes with tests but no test methods. In other cases it is enough to call `descriptor.getChildren()` to get the test methods but with Kotlintest I get empty list.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I guess we need to see more code in order to help. It’s not clear to me if you want to write a KotlinTestEngine or use an existing one. Since a test engine usually creates test descriptors by looking at the tests themselves we would also need to see those.

Comment: There's not a lot of code so far... I need to get list of test methods from the test engine. Now it only gives me classes but I need the methods themselves.

Comment: Maybe there are no valid test methods (in the eyes of KotlinTest). But we can only find out if you show the code you use in your experiments.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code doesn't work is because KotlinTest doesn't honour package name selectors. This could be considered a bug in KotlinTest.

It does honour classpath, class, directory and uri selectors though.

Edit:

As of 3.2 KotlinTest now supports package selectors so your code will work.

Comment: This is fixed in the 3.2.0 release (pending as I write this)